# Category of continuous functions with compact support in the space of continuous bounded functions and in itself

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category, function-spaces

All functions here are from R to R and I use the supremum metric d.

$C_c$= continuous functions with compact support and $C_b$ = continuous bounded functions.

We say a metric space $(X,d)$ is of first category if it can be written as a countable union of nowhere dense (rare) subsets. Otherwise, it is of second category.

> a) What is a category of $C_c$ in $C_b?$
>
> b) What is a category of $C_c$ in itself?

As far as I know, $(C_b,d)$ is complete, so we can also use Baire's category theorem. I already show that the completion of $C_c$ is $C_0$; continuous functions vanishing at infinity. I guess this implies that $C_c$ cannot be dense in $C_b$, so maybe this fact might be useful for part a). To be honest, for part b) I have no idea.

Comment: Hint: for (b), observe that $C_c$ is the countable ascending union of subspaces $V_N$, consisting of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ supported on $[-N,N]$, with $N=1,2,3,\ldots$. Show that $V_N$ is nowhere dense in $V_{N+1}$...

Comment: By "functions supported on $[-N,N]$", do we mean functions that are zero outside of $[-N,N]$? Because if we define $V_N$ as the functions $f$ with $\text{supp}f = [-N,N]$ then it seems ${V_N}$ with $N=1,2,3,\ldots
$ does not cover the whole $C_c$.

Comment: "supported on" means "with support *contained* in".

Comment: @paulgarret Your hint for (b) also works for (a), doesn't it? And  Baire's category theorem is of no use here, as well as $\overline{C_c}=C_0$, is it?

Comment: I guess we can show that in both cases it is of first category by using @paul garrett's idea.

Comment: Just as you say, @Anne Bauval, both of my insights are of no use to the question. I noticed this later.